# Svelte 3 getContext: Doesn't Get Store in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, svelte

In recent browsers (Chrome 78 / Safari 13 / Firefox 70), a store set inside a context seems to work as expected, as such:

```js
// stores.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { setContext, getContext } from 'svelte';

function createStore(key) {
  const store = writable();
  setContext(key, store);
  return store;
}

export function getStore(key) {
  const store = getContext(key);
  if (!store) {
    return createStore(key);
  }
  return store;
}
```

And used in a component as such:

```js
// Form.svelte
import { getStore } from '../stores/stores.js';
import Header from './Header.svelte'
export let incomingPages;

const currentPage = getStore('currentPage')
const numberOfPages = getStore('numberOfPages')
$currentPage = 0
$numberOfPages = Object.keys(incomingPages).length
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper" >
  <Header />

  <div class="page">
    <svelte:component this={pages[$currentPage].page}
                      descriptiveCopy={pages[$currentPage].descriptiveCopy} 
                      question={pages[$currentPage].question} />
  </div>
</div>
```

and then the header component as a child of form...

```js
// Header.svelte
import { getStore } from '../stores/stores.js'
const totalPages = getStore('numberOfPages')
const currentPage = getStore('currentPage')
```

```html
<div class="u-progress">
  <span>{$currentPage + 1} of {$totalPages - 1}</span>
</div>
```

But doesn't seem to work in ie11 (I'm aware there is not necessarily support for ie11 in svelte).
I am trying to debug it, but I don't understand how context works.  Since the getStore function finds no store matching the key, it creates a new unrelated store.  Could this be solved with babel ES6 -> ES5?  I did an initial test including babel, but to no avail...  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context API makes use of `Map` objects, which don't exist in IE11. You'll need to bring a [polyfill](https://polyfill.io/v3/).

Comment: Thanks Rich!  That did it.   P.s. – Big fan!